# create partitions by a non-owner user

Tags: postgresql, privileges, database-partitioning

I am the owner of a partitioned table (table_name) and I have granted the privileges to another user (user2).

`GRANT All ON table_name TO user2`

But whenn user2 want to create a partition of table_name :

`create table table_name_1 partition of table_name for values from (0) to (10)`

the next error appears:

> must be owner of table table_name

Is there any way to allow this user to create a partition without making him the owner of this table?

Answer (score 1):

Only the table owner (that extends to members of that role) or a superuser can create a partition. You cannot grant the privilege to anyone else unless you make them a member of the table owner:

```
GRANT my_user TO user2;
```